# My header covers what I want to make appear.

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

[image]

I ran `rails generate scaffold pins description:string`. The header covers pins as below. I don't know how to fix this. I tried some with css but didn't work. Does anyone know solutions for this?

Comment: Please post your html and css code

Comment: `<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Pins</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= pin.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', pin %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Pin', new_pin_path %>`

Comment: You say you tried some css, post that too. Post the content of the layout file as well. Add them to your question, not the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying `margin-top` to the content of the page. The margin should be the same height as the header or greater.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a bootstrap navbar - you need to add padding to avoid the overlap - from [navbar docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)

```
Add .navbar-fixed-top and include a .container or .container-fluid to center and pad navbar content.

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Body padding required**

The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the `<body>`. Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.

```
body { padding-top: 70px; }
```

Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.